# How to make slideshow work with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have set up the start to my angularJS web app. I am using angularJS page injection and that all works fine. I have also implemented a slideshow background on one of the pages using jquery.

This works correctly until I change the page and return to the slideshow page. The slideshow then dissapears:

```
    $(window).load(function(){
         $('.flexslider').flexslider({
```

I am assuming that is because the window is not reloaded each time the page is viewed due to angularjs page injection.

How would I go about making the slideshow load each time the page is viewed?

Comment: initialize in a directive

Comment: I followed the example in the link above and it has not changed anything?

Comment: I wouldn't use something like flexslider.  Angular comes with a version of jQueryLite as well.  I would look into [bootstrap-ui carousel](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) which is designed to work with angular where ass something like flexslider is meant for for CMS.